# UML Designer opens additional activity explorer when eclipse is started

Tags: uml-designer

UML designer 7.1:
Every time I start eclipse and there are models open, including an already open activity explorer, it opens a new activity explorer. so in the end i have 2, 3, 4 etc activity explorers open if i do not close them.
anyway to stop that?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug can you add an issue in the bug tracker in order that we could have a look on it since the next 8.0 release for july: https://github.com/ObeoNetwork/UML-Designer/issues/new